# When does a map between 4-manifolds map boundary to boundary upto homotopy?

Tags: reference-request, smooth-manifolds, 3-manifolds, 4-manifolds

Let $f:M\to N$ be a smooth map between smooth 4-manifolds with boundary. When does $f$ map boundary of $M$ to boundary of $N$ upto homotopy i.e. when there is a map $F:M\to N$ homotopic to $f$ such that $F(\delta(M))\subseteq\delta(N)$? Can I impose some kind of condition on $M$, $N$ or $f$ such that $F$ maps boundary to boundary?

I apologize if my question is too naïve or too basic.
Any kind of suggestions will be helpful. Thanks@RyanBudney for reformulating the question.

Comment: Could you define a submersion of manifolds with boundary? Is the self-map $x\to x/2$ of the unit disk a submersion?

Comment: I deleted my comment as it was wrong (sorry!) (a smooth submersion between two **boundaryless** smooth manifolds of the same dimension is a local diffeomorphism, see Proposition 4.8. of Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds ). The counterexample (for manifold with boundary) is given in the @IgorBelegradek comment.

Comment: Without a refinement to your question, the answer is "almost never".  The title of your question is different than the question in the body of your post.  Both could be made more interesting by adding "up to 1-parameter families", i.e. up to homotopy for the title question, and up to 1-parameter families of submersions for the body question.  But you should decide on what question you want to ask.

Comment: Thanks@IgorBelegradek for the clarification.

Comment: I voted to close because it is unclear what you are asking. As Ryan says one reasonable question would be: "under what condition a map of compact 4-manifolds is homotopic to a  map that takes boundary to the boundary". And it is probably better to specify which 4-manifolds you care about. There is no general result.

Comment: Dear@IgorBelegradek I have already apologized for asking a naive question. Any smooth affine surface is homotopic to   a 4-manifolds with boundary so my main interest are those 4 manifolds with boundary which are homotopic to a smooth affine surface.

Comment: So what is wrong with the tautological condition that $f$ maps boundary to boundary?  This is probably as simple as it gets, given your set-up.  Your question is about as unmotivated as "which infinite sets contain the integers?"   The answer is, any set that contains the integers.

Comment: @RyanBudney can you give a nontrivial example when boundary maps to boundary?

Comment: 1) The unit disc in the plane, $z \longmapsto z^2$.  2) Take the identity map on a manifold, and slightly perturb it away from the boundary. 3) Let the manifold be $[-1,1]$ and take the map $t \longmapsto t^2$.  $2$-manifolds have quite a rich collection of homotopy classes of maps.  $3$-manifolds even more rich.

Comment: Thanks@RyanBudney. Can you give some references where cases of 3-manifolds or 4-manifolds have been discussed?

Comment: I suppose it depends on what question you want to see discussed.  Your question as-asked is trivial, so people do not discuss it.  But if you ask it up to homotopy, or up to 1-parameter families of submersions, etc, this is a classical problem.  For maps of surfaces it's now a fairly easy question to answer. The terminology is "peripheral systems".  For 3-manifolds, this question largely goes back to the initial work leading up to the JSJ-decomposition, and Waldhausen's work, and the answer is analogous to the surface case.

Comment: For 4-manifolds there's less work, but much of what you see happen in low dimensions generalizes.

Comment: Thanks@RyanBudney now I will look into the literature. I have edited my question also.